# What is gcc -O2 doing to the recursive Fibonacci function?

Tags: gcc, assembly, recursion, x86

I am learning x86 assembler in order to write a compiler. In particular, I'm taking a variety of simple recursive functions and feeding them through different compilers (OCaml, GCC etc.) in order to get a better understanding of the kinds of assembler generated by different compilers.

I've got a trivial recursive integer Fibonacci function:

```
int fib(int x) { return (x < 2 ? x : fib(x-1)+fib(x-2)); }
```

My hand-coded assembly looks like this:

```
fib:
    cmp eax, 2
    jl  fin
    push    eax
    dec eax
    call    fib
    push    eax
    mov eax, [esp+4]
    add eax, -2
    call    fib
    add eax, [esp]
    add esp, 8
fin:
    ret
```

Compiling that function to Intel-syntax assembler using `gcc -O2` produces this enigmatic code:

```
_fib:
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx
    sub esp, 16
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [esp+32]
    cmp edi, 1
    jle L4
    mov ebx, edi
    xor esi, esi
L3:
    lea eax, [ebx-1]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
    call    _fib
    sub ebx, 2
    add esi, eax
    cmp ebx, 1
    jg  L3
    and edi, 1
L2:
    lea eax, [esi+edi]
    add esp, 16
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    ret
L4:
    xor esi, esi
    jmp L2
```

So I guess the calling convention is argument at `[esp+4]` and return value in `eax`. It starts by pushing `edi`, `esi` and `ebx`. Then it claims another 16 bytes for a stack frame, enough for 4 temporary ints. Then `edi` is read from `[esp+32]`, which is the argument. If the argument is `<=1` then it jumps to `L4` which zeroes out (?) `esi` before jumping back to `L2` which sets `eax=esi+edi` which is just the argument `edi`. If the argument was `>1` then the argument is copied into `ebx` and zeroes `esi` before falling through into `L3`. In `L3`, it sets `eax=ebx-1` and stores the result (n-1) at `esp` in the stack frame before recursing to calculate `fib(n-1)`. The result is added to `esi`, `ebx` is set to `n-2` and it loops back to `L3` if `ebx>1` otherwise it extracts the lower bit of `edi` before falling through to `L2`.

Why is this code so convoluted (e.g. is there a name for an optimization that has been done that I'm not seeing?)?

The recursive calls `fib(n-2)` seem to have been replaced with a loop accumulating in `esi` but that call wasn't in tail position so how was this done?

What is the purpose of the `and edi, 1`?

What is the purpose of the `mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax`?

Why is the stack frame so large?

Can you disassemble this algorithm back into C to make it clearer what is going on?

My preliminary impression is that GCC generates pretty poor x86 assembler. In this case, over 2× more code for equal performance (3.25s for fib(40) on this 1.6GHz Atom for both programs). Is that fair?

Comment: longer x86 code doesn't necessary mean WORSE x86 code. Some short sequences can actually be much LESS efficient, time-wise, than longer sequences. Don't knock the GCC version until you've profiled both versions.

Comment: Have you compared the runtimes?

Comment: Actually GCC is pretty good at optimizing ;) The code doesn't look well, but that's x86 "poor" implementation's fault :P

Comment: "Can you disassemble this algorithm back into C [...]?" Wouldn't that just be assembling?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, I have compared the runtimes and they are the same (3.25s on this 1.6GHz Intel Atom).

Comment: Optimizations will depend on which -march= option you supply.  I don't know which gcc version you have but `-march=atom`, `-mtune=atom`, etc were apparently added in gcc 4.5; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110674/gcc-optimization-flags-for-intel-atom.

Comment: @MarcB So far, `gcc -O2` has generated much longer programs that are no faster (often substantially slower) in every single case including this one. `gcc -O3` has generated code slightly faster than my assembler but it is 80× longer!

Comment: @torek Excellent point. This is gcc 4.6.1. I'll try it...

Comment: @torek Optimizing for Atom produces slightly shorter and simpler code (mainly because it has one fewer instruction blocks) but it is ~2% slower.

Comment: Well, that just says that `-march=atom` is not quite doing the right thing (that other thread implies that really getting optimal results is tricky).  I'm sure instruction weights, etc., get changed in every new gcc these days, depending on who has had time to work on what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the comments above, note that the recursion *has* been unwound into a tail call by replacing:

```
return x < 2 ? x : fib(x - 2) + fib(x - 1);
```

with:

```
if ((xprime = x) < 2) {
    acc = 0;
} else {
    /* at this point we know x >= 2 */
    acc = 0; /* start with 0 */
    while (x > 1) {
       acc += fib(x - 1); /* add fib(x-1) */
       x -= 2; /* now we'll add fib(x-2) */
    }
    /* so at this point we know either x==1 or x==0 */
    xprime = x == 1 ? 1 : 0; /* ie, x & 1 */
}
return xprime + acc;
```

I suspect this rather tricky loop arose from multiple optimization steps, not that I have fiddled with gcc optimization since about gcc 2.3 (it's all very different inside now!).

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, `fib(x-2)` is equal to `fib(x-3) + fib(x-4)`, `fib(x-4)` is equal to `fib(x-5) + fib(x-6)` etc. so `fib(x)` is being calculated as `fib(x-1) + fib(x-3) + fib(x-5) + ... + fib(x&1)` (`fib(x&1)` equals `x&1`) i.e. gcc has inlined the call to `fib(x-2)`, which is quite a clever thing to do to a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

This first part is ensuring registers that should be preserved according to the calling convention are not trashed. I would guess the calling convention used here is `cdecl`.

```
_fib:
    push    edi
    push    esi
    push    ebx
    sub esp, 16
```

`DWORD PTR[esp+32]` is your `x`:

```
    mov edi, DWORD PTR [esp+32]
    cmp edi, 1
    jle L4
```

If `x` is less than or equal to 1 (this corresponds to your `x < 2`), then go to `L4` which is:

```
L4:
    xor esi, esi
    jmp L2
```

This zeroes out `esi` and branches to `L2`:

```
L2:
    lea eax, [esi+edi]
    add esp, 16
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi
    ret
```

This sets `eax` (the return value) with `esi+edi`. Since `esi` is 0 already, `edi` is just loaded in the case of 0 and 1. This corresponds to `x < 2 ? x`.

Now we look at the case when `x` is not `< 2`:

```
    mov ebx, edi
    xor esi, esi
L3:
    lea eax, [ebx-1]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
    call    _fib
```

First, `x` is copied to `ebx`, then `esi` is zeroed.

Next, `eax` is set to `x - 1`. This value is moved to the top of the stack and `_fib` called. This corresponds to `fib(x-1)`.

```
    sub ebx, 2
    add esi, eax
```

This subtracts 2 from `ebx` (`x`). Then `eax` (return value from `_fib` call is added to `esi`, which was set to 0 before). Hence `esi` now holds the result of `fib(x-1)`.

```
    cmp ebx, 1
    jg  L3
    and edi, 1
```

`ebx` is compared to 1. If it is greater than 1, then we loop back to `L3`. Otherwise (the case where it is 0 or 1), we perform `and edi, 1` and fall through to `L2` (we analysed what this does earlier already). The `and edi, 1` is equivalent to performing a `%2` on `x`.

From a high level, this is what the code does:

- Sets up stack frame and saves registers
- If `x < 2`, then return `x`.
- Keep calling and summing `fib(x-...)` until `x` is smaller than 2. In this case, fall through to the `x < 2` case.

The optimization is that GCC unwinds the cases where `x >= 2` by doing them in a loop instead of recursively.